# Printing array object at index:i brings up compiler error

Tags: objective-c, arrays, printing

Have a bit of confusion here.

I added a few objects from a class into an array. Now I am trying to iterate through those objects and print them along with all their variables (to console).

```
NSArray *stockArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:stock1, stock2, stock3, nil];

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        StockHolding *stockItem=[[StockHolding alloc]init];
        stockItem=[stockArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [print stockItem];
    }
```

My Stock Holding class has several properties that I declare in .h and synthesize in .m along with the print method.

However, when I try to use it in the above code to print the "stockItem", I am getting compiler error "Use of undeclared identifier 'print'"

This doesn't make sense since the the Stock Holding class declares print in .h and implements in .m:

```
-(void) print{
NSLog(@"Current purchase price is %f, current price is %f, 
number of shares are %i, cost in dollars is %f, value is dollars is %f", 
purchaseSharePrice, currentSharePrice, 
numberOfShares, self.costInDollars, self.valueInDollars);
}
```

Should I be using another way to print these array objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is backwards.  It should be:

```
[stockItem print];
```

Objective-C syntax goes:

```
[object method];
```